# Вёрстка для перевода в PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf

У меня есть задание сверстать страницы, которые в будущем будут переведены в pdf. 
Проблема в том, что `footer` и `header` должны повторяться на каждой странице. Каждые 320px должна быть новая страница с таким футером и хедером. Как это организовать по средствам `CSS` и `HTML`?

`footer`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`header`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: media print - как бы в сети много информации

Comment: @МаксимЛенский насколько я знаю это в медии принт стили только которые используется при печати? Нет?

Comment: они как раз и отвечают за это

Comment: @МаксимЛенский т.е. если я просто открою страницу html, то не будет разделение на страницы?

Comment: я щас проверил в двух вариантах - вёрстка в pdf отображается в 4х браузерах 100% одинково как на странице  а вот при печати уже отображается то что написано в этих правилах ...

Comment: вот ссылка на скрины https://cloud.mail.ru/public/8hJV/foecuxm73  увидешь разницу в выводе в pdf или просто в печать